# SQL. Как передать значение поля таблицы в переменную

Tags: sql

Пишу на T-Sql триггер, срабатывающий на добавление в таблицу Table1 новой строки.
Каждый столбец этой строки содержит имя другой таблицы: Table2, Table3 и т.д. В эти самые таблицы (Table2, Table3 и т.д.) мне нужно вставить новые строки, значения которых вычисляются в триггере.
Проблема следующая: у меня не получается заполнить динамически значение переменной, которая должна содержать в себе имя Table2 или Table3.
Вместо этого переменная @TableName содержит в себе следующее: 'select column1 from Table1 where num_string = sn', где column1 - значение текстовой переменной, sn - значение числовой переменной.
Дальше по коду триггера мне нужно вставить строки в таблицу Table2 или Table3 в зависимости от того, какое значение я выбрал динамически.
Но в итоге падает ошибка о неправильном синтаксисе возле слова insert, ведь когда я пытаюсь динамически выполнить следующую переменную на заполнение, то в ней получается текст 'insert into select colomn1...' вместо 'insert into Table2...'

Написано все таким образом:

```
Set @tablename = 'select '+@num_col+' from Table1 where num_string = '+cast(@num_string as nvarchar(99))+''
exec sp_executesql @tablename

Set @insert = 'insert into '+@tablename+' values(' +@a+','+@b')'
exec sp_executesql @insert
```

Что я делаю не так?
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Имя таблицы должно быть в отдельной переменной.
В параметре для `sp_executesql` задаём имя выходного параметра.
Подробности в справке по [sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
declare @tablename  nvarchar(500)
declare @tableIN    nvarchar(500)
declare @select     nvarchar(500)
declare @param      nvarchar(500)

set @tableIN = 'Table1' -- имя таблицы, в которой ищем

set @param = N'@tableOUT nvarchar(200) OUTPUT' -- имя выходного параметра

set @select = 'select @tableOUT ='+@num_col+' from '+@tableIN+' where num_string = '+cast(@num_string as nvarchar(99))+''

exec sp_executesql @select, @param, @tableOUT = @tablename output

-- в @tablename находится имя другой таблицы

set @insert = 'insert into '+@tablename+' values('+@a+','+@b+')'
exec sp_executesql @insert
```

Comment: Ок. Большое спасибо. Сегодня попробую

Comment: Проверил. Огромное спасибо, все работает. Сам не додумался бы